# Using Boost with C++?

Tags: c++

I'm on Mac OS. I'm using Visual Studio Code.

I'm coding in C++. I recently installed the most recent version of Boost (1.76.0).

**My file name: test.cpp**

I've included this header in my file:

```
#include <boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp>
```

I'm compiling with this command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

My code won't compile. I keep getting this error:

```
'boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp' file not found
```

**Question: What am I doing wrong?**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you install `boost`? Does the file `/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp` exist?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I installed boost in the same directory as my test.cpp file. I looked through the boost library, and it does exist.

Comment: That's not how you should normally do it. Did you install a pre-built boost version or did you build it from source?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm still new to coding haha. I installed the boost library directly from the website, and moved it into my directory. I didn't write / build anything. Is this what you are getting at? Is there something I should be doing?

Comment: You should install Boost in one of the system include paths. If Boost is in the same directory, you should use quotes in the include command. Brackets are for system include paths and quotes are for local paths. `#include "boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp"`

Comment: I suggest that you use a pre-built boost library for your Mac. I don't now the package manager for Mac, but I'd be surprised if it doesn't have boost so you can install it properly.

Comment: I'd recommend using homebrew or Conan to install boost properly

Comment: @vll I tried using the quotes too, but it didn't work!

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'll try installing boost another way! Thank you

Comment: @AlanBirtles ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, whenever you use g++, you need to define your include folders with `-I` switch, in this case you can say:

```cpp
g++ -Iboost -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

here boost is the name of the folder that your .h/.hpp files are inside it.

**Update**

Here is also a link that completely explain about how to use boost library: [Link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)

Comment: I tried doing this, but it didn't work! In your response, what would boost be? In order to get to the scoped_ptr.hpp file, you need to go through boost/smart_ptr. Would the command be g++ -I boost/smart_ptr -std=c++11 test.cpp? @saeid

Comment: boost is the name of the main folder of the boost, that other libraries of the boost are inside it

Comment: @ilt_coding btw, here is the official boost library page that refer to this: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/compute/doc/html/boost_compute/getting_started.html

Comment: referring to the main boost page, the folder should contain boost subdirectory! so: `-Iparent_of_boost_folder` should works fine.

Comment: Whenever I use boost, I should be using this flag?

Comment: Yes, but if you use `CMake`, or easier than it `make`, you can do it easier(automatically)

Comment: got it, will do

Comment: Remember, it's not about just `boost`, every library you are using, need to be included to your include path, and if it has compiled files too, you need to add those with `-l` switch

Comment: here is a tutorial about `make` (if you are in linux, it's really common tool there): https://makefiletutorial.com/

Comment: good to know, will definitely look into make